# I created three div with no content with same class and give them width 100% but when i put height 1px to make line they all have different height why

Tags: html, css

[Click here It is a gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8otv.gif)

See the gif when i am changing the height from 1px to 2px they all have different height after 3px they height is same. What is happening here is it a rendering issue

this is my code

```css
    nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
    .menuLine {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #000000);
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }
```

```html
    <header>
    <nav>
    <div class="menuLine"></div>
    <div class="menuLine"></div>
    <div class="menuLine"></div>
    </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: There is a typo in your example, `background-color: #000000);` There should probably be no close parentheses.

Comment: `height: 1px` in combination with `border-radius: 2px` and `box-sizing: border-box` doesn't really make sense...

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to "HiDPI" screens.

There's kinda no such thing as "1px" on modern displays. They are probably all the same size, but the video driver/monitor are dithering them differently due to rounding (2x and 3x are pretty common).

Have a look at resolution independent units like `pt` for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units

Other than that, the border radius is larger than the border height (2px > 1px), so I would expect the rendering behavior to be ambiguous.

Your code, on macOS, and a HiDPI display in both Safari and Firefox, renders correctly. I don't have Chrome installed, but you should check other browsers to see if it's a rendering engine difference, or possibly a display resolution problem.